# Json.NET serialization strange behaviour

Tags: .net, json

I have string
"acount":"3Jmz2251olK5r\/9uOUAWhrp0="

when I used  JsonConvert.DeserializeObject("acount":"3Jmz2251oO+llK5r\/9uOUAWhrp0=");

The char \ disappeared from account string.

Do you know somebody, how can I resolve it ?

I am using .NET 2.0.

Thanks 
Tomas

Comment: I cannot see any backslash in your account. Do you mean forward slash?

Answer (score 0):

A backslash in C# escapes the next character. To put a real backslash into the string, you need to use a double-backslash:

```
"3Jmz2251oO+llK5r\\/9uOUAWhrp0="
```

Or you can use a literal string:

```
@"3Jmz2251oO+llK5r\/9uOUAWhrp0="
```

Comment: Actually there is a double-backslash. The account string comes from another application, after deserialization by Json.NET \\ disappeared. Thanks.

Comment: @Tomas: The backslash is also used as an escape character in javascript, so if the original string had two backslashes it is correct for the resulting string to only have one backslash when you deserialize the JSON.

Comment: I am using Json.net opensource library, because my project is running on .Net 2.0 and this library remove backslash in object property, which is deserializes. Thanks

Comment: @Tomas: Yes, this is correct behavior. A backslash in JSON is an escape character for the character following it. When it is deserialized, it should be removed.